# Impute binary values in python

Tags: python, imputation

I have a dataframe with missing values that where the posible options are True or False
since there are NaN cases pandas is taking the column as a float one, and after imputing 
that column and getting the values: 0, 0.5 and 1

How can I add a constrain to only get 0 and 1? 
currently I'm using the missingpy  library

```
from missingpy import MissForest
```

Comment: Please show some code and an example for your dataframe (input and expected output).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind updating your question with some examples of the data your using and the code that's giving you the issues - it will make the answers you get better!

From what your saying it looks like the model being fit is considering your target variable as continuous and not categorical (boolean is essentially categorical 0 or 1). The API documentation on MissForest says:

> The first step involves filling any missing values of the remaining,
>   non-candidate, columns with an initial guess, which is the column mean
>   for columns representing numerical variables and the column mode for
>   columns representing categorical variables. Note that the categorical
>   variables need to be explicitly identified during the imputer's fit()
>   method call (see API for more information).

This means you should specify `cat_vars` during the fit stage:

> fit(self, X, y=None, cat_vars=None):
>       Fit the imputer on X.
>
> ```
> Parameters
> ----------
> X : {array-like}, shape (n_samples, n_features)
>     Input data, where ``n_samples`` is the number of samples and
>     ``n_features`` is the number of features.
>
> cat_vars : int or array of ints, optional (default = None)
>     An int or an array containing column indices of categorical
>     variable(s)/feature(s) present in the dataset X.
>     ``None`` if there are no categorical variables in the dataset.
>
> Returns
> -------
> self : object
>     Returns self.
> ```

Reference [here](https://pypi.org/project/missingpy/).

This will mean that'll impute using the categories and not with continuous values.

Answer (score 1):

You have several strategies dealing with `nan`, let's consider this toy `df`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'column': [np.nan, True, np.nan]
    }
)
print(df['column'])

>>> 
0     NaN
1    True
2     NaN
Name: column, dtype: object
```

You can simply force the column to a `bool` type if you can afford working with corrupt data (not advisable):

```py
print(df['column'].astype(bool))

>>> 
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: column, dtype: bool
```

You can remove the rows that contain `nan` (the best approach):

```py
print(df['column'].dropna())

>>>
1    True
Name: column, dtype: object
```

Or you can replace those `nan` with a default value:

```py
print(df['column'].fillna(False))

>>>
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: column, dtype: bool
```